# Automatically click a hyperlink in jquery/js

Tags: javascript, jquery, hyperlink, plupload

I have a link where I need to be click it automatically using jquery or js.

If I click on the link the files are removing but I need to do it automatically after uploading all the files.

Actually I;musing plupload and it has functonality to remove all the files for jquery UI as  `$('#uploader').plupload('clearQueue');` but this is not working!

This is my link

```
<a id="deleteallfiles" href="#">[Remove all files]</a>
```

This my script:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    // Convert divs to queue widgets when the DOM is ready
    $(function () {
        $("#uploader").plupload({
            // General settings
            runtimes: 'gears,flash,silverlight,browserplus,html5',
            url: 'Final.aspx',
            max_file_size: '10mb',
            max_file_count: 25,
            chunk_size: '1mb',
            unique_names: true,

            // Resize images on clientside if we can
            //                    resize: { width: 320, height: 240, quality: 90 },

            // Specify what files to browse for
            filters: [
        { title: "Image files", extensions: "jpg,gif,png" },
        { title: "Zip files", extensions: "zip" }
    ],

            // Flash settings
            flash_swf_url: 'js/plupload.flash.swf',

            // Silverlight settings
            silverlight_xap_url: 'js/plupload.silverlight.xap'
        });


        // Client side form validation
        $('form').submit(function (e) {
            var uploader = $('#uploader').plupload('getUploader');

            // Files in queue upload them first
            if (uploader.files.length > 0) {
                // When all files are uploaded submit form
                uploader.bind('StateChanged', function () {
                    if (uploader.files.length === (uploader.total.uploaded + uploader.total.failed)) {
                        $('form')[0].submit();
                    }
                });

                uploader.start();
            }
            else
                alert('You must at least upload one file.');

            return false;
        });
        var uploader = $('#uploader').plupload('getUploader');
        uploader.bind('FileUploaded', function (up, file, res) {
            $('#showfilelist').append("<div id=" + file.id + " class='thumb'><a href='uploads/" + document.getElementById("currentDirectory").value + "/" + file.name + "' target='_blank' rel='gallery'><img src='uploads/" + document.getElementById("currentDirectory").value + "/" + file.name + "' width='50' height='50'/></a></div>");

          });

        //            $('#uploader').plupload('clearQueue');

        $('#deleteallfiles').click(function (e) {
            $.each(uploader.files, function (i, file) {
                uploader.splice(file);
            });
        });

      });

</script>
```

Comment: You just use the click() function.

Comment: Yes I tried this way document.getElementById("deleteallfiles").click = document.getElementById("deleteallfiles").disabled = true; it but didn't work.

Comment: Make sure you are using jquery to assign the event handler AND invoke the event, otherwise you may have issues. jQuery won't know about the handler if you use document.getElementById to assign... 'click' is just a property, remember.

Comment: Thanks for all your suggestions and may be something going wrong with my script I will look into it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just use the click function. ie

```
$('#someElement').click();
```

Answer (score 4):

```
$('#someElement').trigger('click');
```

Answer (score 2):

Do can just do:

```
$("a").click();
```

I think that could be the simpelst way to trigger the click event.

From the [jquery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/click/):

Its just a shorthand for the:

```
.trigger('click')
```

Answer (score 1):

I think its as simple as this (tested in IE):

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
    function simulateClick() {
          var el = document.getElementById('deleteallfiles');
          el.click(); 
    }
</script>
```

Here is a reference from W3S: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_all.asp

and here's another implementation with jQuery: http://api.jquery.com/click/

Answer (score 1):

`$("#deleteallfiles").trigger("click")` Should work as you have a jquery click handler defined.

Answer (score 1):

Simply utilize the [click()](http://api.jquery.com/click/) event handler within jQuery:

> Description: Bind an event handler to the "click" JavaScript event, or
>   trigger that event on an element.

If no function() is specified then the event will be triggered by simply attaching the desired event to the desired element:

```
 $('#target').click();
```

This is actually a common thing that I see people overlook way too much.